# Nokogiri Mechanize Parsing Issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, mechanize

I am using the Mechanize gem to parse through the webpage 
http://www.opentable.com/rest_profile_menu.aspx?rid=116320&scpref=96&tab=1

To get the contents inside .menu class but it fetches only the name of the restaurant

When I type the commands:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

agent.get("http://www.opentable.com/rest_profile_menu.aspx?rid=116320&scpref=96&tab=1").link_with(:text =>"Menu").click.search(".menu")
```

I get the output as:
"Sorry, we have no menus available for this restaurant at this time. Please check back later" ;where as I can see a lot of output  in browser.

Please help me find a solution to get the contents.

Comment: When you ask about parsing HTML or XML, you should include a minimal piece of the content so we can test it. Don't expect us to go to a site via a link; If/when the link dies the question is worthless. Take the time to help us help you. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: @theTinMan I can scrap other websites but I have having issues with this site so I had given the link of this site.

Comment: So don't do that. Link-rot sets in, the link dies, and the question becomes worthless to anyone else looking for answers to the same question. Also, as I mentioned above, you're making it harder for us to help you. Don't do that. Supply us with the information we need, that YOU'D need if someone asked YOU that question. Make it harder for us to help you and you get less help.

Answer (score 2):

The [web page](http://www.opentable.com/rest_profile_menu.aspx?rid=116320&scpref=96&tab=1) you're using uses an AJAX request to load the menu details.

Nokogiri and Mechanize do not support AJAX request pages.

I had the same situation in my project. I used [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) with Nodejs.

Comment: Of course mechanize supports ajax requests. But you have to actually make them.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the HTML contents of all elements with class "menu", then you might want to adjust your code a bit.

1. If you want to access the HTML response from the page in question, I find it easier to assign a variable to your `get` request:

   ```
   page = agent.get("http://www.opentable.com/rest_profile_menu.aspx?rid=116320&scpref=96&tab=1")
   ```
2. `.link_with(:text =>"Menu").click.search(".menu")` may not be exactly what you want to use for "filtering through the HTML elements". Instead you want to use a method on your `page.body` string called `parser`.

   ```
   object_mapped_html = page.parser
   ```

   `parser` object maps all the HTML elements for you so that you can search through them with ease. I prefer using the `css` command, however I would recommend looking at the [Nokogiri tutorial on how to parse through a HTML/XML webpage](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html). An example of what you are looking to accomplish is this:

   ```
   require 'mechanize'

   agent = Mechanize.new
   page = agent.get("http://www.opentable.com/rest_profile_menu.aspx?rid=116320&scpref=96&tab=1")

   html_data_you_are_looking_for = page.parser.css("div.menu")
   ```

   That div with the class you specified does have the HTML data as follows:

   ```
   1.9.3-p429 :046 > page.parser.css("div.menu").text
   => "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t!AY CHIWOWA Menu\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\r\n\tSee the current menu for !AY CHIWOWA in Chicago.\r\n\tRestaurantProfileMenu.OnLoad({FailedText: \"Sorry, we have no menus available for this restaurant at this time. Please check back later.\"});\r\n\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"
   ```
3. I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish but I looked at the webpage with a web inspector and the class for a majority of the items on the menu are `locu-menu-item` or `locu-menus`. Perhaps if you searched through `.locu-menus` or `.locu-menu-items` you might find what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes that's what I am getting where as I should see the data inside the "menuViewer" class so that I can fetch the info of the restaurant.